# Android - decodeBase64 crashes App

Tags: java, android, encryption

I have to encrypt a String but the app doesn't reach the encrypt method, it crashes on load. 
I'm using Apache Commons Codec library.

```
private EditText txtPass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtPass);
public String key = txtPass.getText().toString();
public byte[] key_Array = org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64(key);
```

For some reason, the app crashes in the third line.

My logcat.

```
12-03 14:03:31.441  23420-23420/com.example.cristiano.automacao V/ActivityThread﹕ Class path: /data/app/com.example.cristiano.automacao-2.apk, JNI path: /data/data/com.example.cristiano.automacao/lib
12-03 14:03:31.591  23420-23420/com.example.cristiano.automacao W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve static method 8974: Lorg/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64;.decodeBase64 (Ljava/lang/String;)[B
12-03 14:03:31.601  23420-23420/com.example.cristiano.automacao W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve static method 8984: Lorg/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64;.encodeBase64String ([B)Ljava/lang/String;
12-03 14:03:31.611  23420-23420/com.example.cristiano.automacao W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41c7b438)
```

Any clue about that?

**Updated**

I changed the code to this:

```
public static String key = "1234";
public static byte[] key_Array = decodeBase64(key);
```

But now I got other error

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64
```

Comment: Why are you using the full name "org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64" ?
You have to import the library, and simply use "decodeBase64(key);".

Comment: I changed it. But the problem persists. I think the problem is on Static methods. Check logcat: "unable to resolve static method 8974"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
// decode data from base 64
    private static byte[] decodeBase64(String dataToDecode)
        {
            byte[] dataDecoded = Base64.decode(dataToDecode, Base64.DEFAULT);
            return dataDecoded;
        }

//enconde data in base 64
        private static byte[] encodeBase64(byte[] dataToEncode)
        {
            byte[] dataEncoded = Base64.encode(dataToEncode, Base64.DEFAULT);
            return dataEncoded;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply create an object of Base64 and use it to encode or decode in Android, when using *org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64* library

## To Encode

> Base64 ed=new Base64();
>
> String encoded=new String(ed.encode("Hello".getBytes()));

Replace "Hello" with the text to be encoded in String Format.

## To Decode

> Base64 ed=new Base64();
>
> String decoded=new String(ed.decode(encoded.getBytes()));

Here encoded is the String variable to be decoded

Answer (score 0):

you are giving a string as an input
you should give key.getBytes() to the decode methos