# Java: How to convert String to base64string?

Tags: java, android, string, decode

I am using this method to decrypt my incoming messages:

```
private static String decrypt(String key, String initVector, String dataToDecrypt) {
    try {
        IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(initVector.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, iv);

        String safeString = dataToDecrypt.replace('-', '+').replace('_', '/');
        byte[] decodedString = Base64.decodeBase64(safeString);

        byte[] original = cipher.doFinal(decodedString);

        return new String(original);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

However, my `Android` app crashes, showing the following exception:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method
>   decodeBase64(Ljava/lang/String;)[B in class
>   Lorg/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64; or its super classes
>   (declaration of 'org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64' appears in
>   /system/framework/ext.jar)

accordingly, the method `decodeBase64` takes `base64string`, but I pass `string`. Here comes my question:

How to convert `String` to `base64string` ?!

**Please note that I am trying to DECODE not ENCODE. Almost all the solutions provided are for the encoding part which is not my worry.**

P.S.: I am developing an Android-app on Android-Studio

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apache Commons Codec with Android: could not find method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047706/apache-commons-codec-with-android-could-not-find-method)

Comment: @Kiskae : with my all respect, this is definitely not a duplicate. I am asking a very different question. He ia asking : "Android: could not find method, how to solve?" .. Meanwhile, I am asking about a very precise matter which is "how to convert string to base64string" .. if the source of the problem isthe  same, that does not mean the question is duplicated. I have to say, this is unfair (the downvotes, the close request and the duplicate question charge. But, by the end of the day I just want to learn and get better. Thanks )

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - decodeBase64 crashes App](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27276539/android-decodebase64-crashes-app)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this:

```
Base64.encodeToString(mStringToEncode.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP)
```

it exist many encoding mode use autocompletion to see more Base64.NO_WRAP, Base64.CRLF, etc...

you need to import package:

```
import android.util.Base64;
```

Comment: I am sorry but this didn't work.Beside, I am trying to decode not encode.

Comment: This helped a lot , it seems I was mistakenly putting the wrong import: `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64` .. now it works

Answer (score 2):

```
public static String toBase64(String value){
    if (value == null)
        value = "";
    return Base64.encodeToString(value.trim().getBytes(), android.util.Base64.DEFAULT);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27278004/4606266)

```
        // decode data from base 64
        private static byte[] decodeBase64(String dataToDecode)
        {
            byte[] dataDecoded = Base64.decode(dataToDecode, Base64.DEFAULT);
            return dataDecoded;
        }

       //enconde data in base 64
        private static byte[] encodeBase64(byte[] dataToEncode)
        {
            byte[] dataEncoded = Base64.encode(dataToEncode, Base64.DEFAULT);
            return dataEncoded;
        }
```

Comment: Yes, but it is not working .. at the moment I am trying to understand why ! .. meanwhile I posted the original problem I am having

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
private static String encryptNew(String key, String initVector, String dataToEncrypt) throws Exception{

        byte[] plainTextbytes = dataToEncrypt.getBytes("UTF-8");
        byte[] keyBytes = key.getBytes("UTF-8");
        byte[] IvkeyBytes = initVector.getBytes("UTF-8");

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding");
        SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
        IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(IvkeyBytes);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, ivParameterSpec);
        plainTextbytes = cipher.doFinal(plainTextbytes);
        return Base64.encodeToString(plainTextbytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
    }

    private static String decrypt(String key, String initVector, String dataToDecrypt) {
            try {

                byte[] cipheredBytes = Base64.decode(dataToDecrypt, Base64.DEFAULT);
                byte[] keyBytes = key.getBytes("UTF-8");
                byte[] IvkeyBytes = initVector.getBytes("UTF-8");

                Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding");
                SecretKeySpec secretKeySpecy = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
                IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(IvkeyBytes);
                cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpecy, ivParameterSpec);
                cipheredBytes = cipher.doFinal(cipheredBytes);

                return new String(cipheredBytes,"UTF-8");
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }
```